# Replace current collection item in IEnumerable anonymous statement with result of statement

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I currently have the following statements written:

```
List <string> eventTablesList = GetStringArgument("arg_event_tables", "UNKNOWN")
    .Split(',')
    .ToList<string>()
List<string> qualifiedStagingEventTableNamesList = new List<string>();

eventTablesList.ForEach(
    eventTable => qualifiedStagingEventTableNamesList.Add(
        ControlSQLCommand.GetQualifiedNameByKeyName(
            eventTable, 
            "arg_insert_staging_event_table")));
```

Notice that I have two lists. I would like to only have `eventTablesList` and simply manipulate the list to overwrite the current element in itself. I originally tried this as follows:

```
eventTablesList.ForEach(
    eventTable => eventTable = ControlSQLCommand.GetQualifiedNameByKeyName(
        eventTable, 
        "arg_insert_staging_event_table")))
```

I originally believed that the anonymous function used a pointer to the current element in the collection within the LINQ query. I can see this is not the case as the `eventTablesList` elements are never overwritten after the above LINQ query is run. Is there any suggestions to make this more lightweight/elegant?

Comment: You only have one LINQ method in all of your code, and it's the `ToList` method.  None of the rest of your code is using LINQ.  LINQ would be well suited to solving this problem, if you actually used it though.

Comment: You might want to read Eric Lippert's blog post [“foreach” vs “ForEach”](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/)

Comment: If you stop thinking about *mutating lists* and start thinking about *computing results*, your code will start to get more lightweight and elegant.

Comment: @EricLippert This is useful advice. I always viewed query-based .net coding as IEnumerable manipulations

Comment: @Rice: Though it is *correct* to view queries as manipulating sequences, you can be more general than that. Queries represent the abstract notions of filtering, sorting, projecting and grouping data *regardless* of whether the data is sequential, tabular, or hierarchical. (Hence LINQ to Objects, LINQ to SQL and LINQ to XML.)  Sequences are just a special case of the power of queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this as one Linq expression then you'll want to use `Select`

```
List<string> eventTablesList = GetStringArgument("arg_event_tables", "UNKNOWN")
    .Split(',')
    .Select(eventTable => ControlSQLCommand.GetQualifiedNameByKeyName(
        eventTable, 
        "arg_insert_staging_event_table"))
    .ToList()
```

The idea here is that `Select` will translate the string values in your comma separated list to the string values returned by calling `ControlSQLCommand.GetQualifiedNameByKeyName`.

The reason your `ForEach` version isn't working is because `eventTable` is a copy of the reference in the list that points to the string.  So assigning a new value to it does not change where the reference in the list points.  It would work if you were instead mutating the object the reference points to, but since `string` is immutable that wouldn't work either.

Jon Skeet has a very nice blog post that covers how parameters are passed in C# called
[Parameter passing in C#](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html)

Comment: I wasn't aware that parameters in in IEnumerable methods were, like regular c# methods, also pass-by-value. Since strings are immutable, I am assuming that the original reference of the string in eventTablesList is overwritten by eventTable's reference after its result has been computed by my GetQualifiedNameByKeyName() method?  This works exactly as intended, thank you for your help.

Comment: @Rice Well the lambda that you pass is really just a short hand for a delegate which is basically a method.  Note you'd have the same issue if you did a regular `foreach`, but you could do it with a `for` since you'd be accessing the list by index directly.

Answer (score 0):

Simply assign the result of the following `Select`-statement to `eventTablesList`:

```
eventTablesList = eventTablesList.Select(x => ControlSQLCommand.GetQualifiedNameByKeyName(
        x, 
        "arg_insert_staging_event_table"));
```